# Why have Samaritans not built a temple on Mt. Gerizim?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, non-rabbinic-judaism

According to the Samaritan Pentateuch, Mt. Gerizim is the place where Hashem would like his Temple constructed. No temple currently stands on Mt. Gerizim.

The reasons (political and theological) that no Jewish temple has been built in *Jerusalem* in modern days under Rabbinic Judaism are well known.

Why have *Samaritans* not built (or rebuilt) a temple at Mt. Gerizim? Is the delay is more practical in nature (e.g. lack of funds, lack of architectural skills, refusal of building permits, fear of sectarian violence, or simple apathy) or are they delaying the construction for doctrinal reasons (e.g. waiting for Messiah, waiting for a certain sign in the heavens, etc.).

Comment: Is this a question about Judaism?

Comment: Related meta post: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4388/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio thank you. I posted that Meta question several weeks ago because I wasn't sure if this was on-topic. I got upvotes but the only other response I got was a mod posting links that seemed to indicate that Samaritanism *was* considered to be a form of Judaism *as such is defined in the scope of this site*. If Samaritanism is off-topic, this should be made clear on Meta.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - I don't think Samaritanism is Judaism. Judaism is practiced by _Jews_. Samaritans aren't Jews, nor do they claim to be.

Comment: Robert, I realize it was your meta question and that you didn't get much feedback.  I posted the link here to redirect discussion of whether this is on topic from comments here to that meta thread.